# Ubuntu Tomcat7 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, jdbc, datasource, tomcat7

I'm trying to set up a JDBC DataSource in Tomcat 7 under Ubuntu 12.X, so I added the following to the context.xml file:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="5" maxIdle="2" maxWait="5000"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" username="usr" password="***" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db" />
```

Obviously, using the right and tested database user id and password. When I restart Tomcat, I get the this error:

```
Feb 05, 2013 1:10:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

I googled, and found out the JDBC driver has to be copied to the $CATALINA_HOME/lib folder, so I copied the postgresql-9.2-1000.jdbc4.jar to /usr/share/tomcat7/lib, but it didn't help. I tried copying the file to other locations, with the same results.

Another attempt was to change the tomcat-dbcp.jar symlink in /usr/share/tomcat7/lib from ../../java/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar to ../../java/tomcat-dbcp.jar. The only change was I got only one warning instead of four, but the datasource doesn't work either.

Java version:

```
jdoe@sever:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.4) (7u9-2.3.4-0ubuntu1.12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

Any hint, very welcomed.

Cheers.

Comment: The double `dbcp` in `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory` is rather suspicious.

Comment: Don't want to necro, but the double dbcp in the package name is correct. tomcat-dbcp.jar is basically a refactored/repackaged version of commons-dbcp.jar and this package is correct.

Comment: Thanks for asking! Got hit by this too

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The library `tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar` from repositories is corrupted.

Replace it with:

`sudo wget -O /usr/share/java/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/7.0.30/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar`

Comment: OMG this angers me. I burned a lot of time yesterday chasing this JNDI issue. Do these 'maintainers' have smoke tests? You're supposed to be able to trust a core server component from a distro, right?

Comment: Wow, I hope they fix this right away. What a pain! I created a hack-around where my pool class just creates a new connection each time using hard coded username&passwords. Thank you for letting me go back and do this the right way!

Comment: for me it didn't work, but I changed the path to /usr/share/java/tomcat7/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar and it worked

Comment: Actually, in Debian, it worked after I copied the aforementioned file to usr/share/tomcat7/lib (not /usr/share/java). There was not such file in the first place, so I didn't replace any corrupted version anyway).

Comment: I got the mixture of the two above on an EZ2 instance. The lib didn't exist at all, and I put it in /usr/share/java/tomcat7/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar. Seems ok. This is why I *never* install Tomcat from the repository and get it from their website instead. You don't get the the managed updates, but that is a small price to pay in comparison.

Answer (score 26):

The cause is a issue in the Ubuntu build/package process for Tomcat7.  If I understand the issue correctly, Apache builds tomcat-dbcp.jar from binary files, while Ubuntu builds packages only from source.  The Ubuntu project ends up needing to change the Java package name, which tends to break things for us poor users.  The gory details may be found at the [Ubuntu issues list](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat6/+bug/283852).

The solution I found is to name the data source factory when I define the resource.  In one case, I have a META-INF/context.xml file that contains:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase"
    username="username" password="password"
    validationQuery="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MY_TABLE"
    factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" />
```

The critical element is the "factory" declaration, which overrides the built-in default.

On our production machines, the resource is defined in the GlobalNamingResources element of the server.xml file.  Specifying the factory is only needed on the Ubuntu systems.

Comment: Note that using this `factory` means that you are no longer using the Tomcat-provided commons-dbcp pool. The Tomcat-provided commons-dbcp pool does in fact have the 'double' `dbcp.dbcp` package name. This is to prevent conflicts with the "real" commons-dbcp library.

Comment: This applies to recent Gentoo as well

Comment: This is how we do it on CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem on CentOS. I got arounbd this by downloading a fresh copy of tomcat from site and uploaded tomcat-dbcp.jar to my online server lib, restart server :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Fedora 20 with Tomcat 7.0.55. I replaced the 7.0.30 with 7.0.55 in the file path and file name and this worked for me. Not sure why but this file was completely missing from the YUM install for tomcat 7. Cant use a database without it.

Answer (score 0):

That did it.

Make sure if the tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar file does not have the below size, then it may be corrupt and you may need to replace it by the sudo wget command above.

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 235411 May  1  2013 tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     22 Jan 10  2013 tomcat-dbcp.jar -> tomcat-dbcp-7.0.30.jar

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel like patching tomcat you can (on CentOS) also add the following to the JAVA_OPTS (e.g. by adding it in /usr/share/tomcat/conf/context.xml

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Djavax.sql.DataSource.Factory=org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
```