# tomcat dbcp and NamingException

Tags: maven, tomcat

I'm getting following errror tomcat 7.0.53 with maven. I used `factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"` in Resource tag in server.xml, but don't know why it is picking up the tomcat dbcp.

Why so?

I did some searching in internet and tried different options like adding tomcat-dbcp in maven, adding to the class path etc.. but nothing seems to work.

Where it went wrong ?

### WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory] Apr 07, 2014 11:39:57 AM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener createMBeans

SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class

Comment: Where do you want to start your tomcat from? (Eclipse, Maven, Integrated Test)

Comment: From debug of eclipse I had set the parameters in eclipse.-Dcatalina.home="/home/bhadram/stsws/ui/tomcat-7.0.53" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="/home/../ui/tomcat-7.0.53/endorsed" -Dcatalina.base="/home/../ui/tomcat-7.0.53" -Djava.io.tmpdir="/home/../ui/tomcat-7.0.53/temp"  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx1024M  -XX:MaxPermSize=200M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a duplication of this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880777/2191131

If this does not work, can you try this? [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268266/can-not-find-class-org-apache-tomcat-dbcp-dbcp-basicdatasourcefactory-in-tomcat7)



Your comment was really helpful because it unveiled the OS :)

Keep me posted on your progress.

Comment: The post in Ubuntu solves the problem.Chaging to org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory solves the problem.