# Amazon ec2 can't find org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-commons-dbcp

I am trying to connect to MySQL service using the following code, but it cannot initialize the database class:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

public class Database {

    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

    static {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        dataSource.setUrl(ServerConfig.DB_URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(ServerConfig.DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(ServerConfig.DB_PASSWORD);
    }

    ...
}
```

Here's the ServerConfig class:

```
public class ServerConfig {

    public static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/relay";
    public static final String DB_USERNAME = "my_username";
    public static final String DB_PASSWORD = "mypassword";

    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.relayapp.server.database.Database
        at com.relayapp.server.model.User.add(User.java:125)
        at com.relayapp.server.request.AddUser.processRequest(AddUser.java:51)
        at com.relayapp.server.request.RelayRequestServlet.doPost(RelayRequestServlet.java:55)
        at com.relayapp.server.request.RelayRequestServlet.doGet(RelayRequestServlet.java:22)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The user credentials seem to be correct, and I can run the `mysql` command successfully. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem seam to be somewhere else, are you using some king of auto Database <-> Java Object binding ?

Comment: No, I am not. Should I give you the full stack trace?

Comment: My only guess is that your runnable cannot find your  
com.relayapp.server.database.Database

is that something you coded yourself?

Comment: The same code (with different ServerConfig credentials) works on my local machine. It breaks down on amazon-aws.

Comment: but how are you running it on your machine vs the aws instance?

Comment: I have tomcat setup on my local machine. I use Eclipse to export a war file to the /webapps folder. It runs on my local tomcat server (with credentials set to my local MySQL), but it breaks down on the ec2.

Comment: You need change the mysql hostname from `localhost` to ec2 IP or public DNS

Comment: did you try opening your war with winrar or something to see if all your libs are included inside your war?

Comment: @BMW Changing the hostname doesn't work. It shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the package `org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880777/1492578) helped fix it. Instead of the `/usr/share/java` folder, tomcat was in the `usr/share/tomcat7` folder, and I ran the command:

```
sudo wget -O /usr/share/tomcat7/tomcat-dbcp-7.0.57.jar http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-dbcp/7.0.57/7tomcat-dbcp-7.0.57.jar
```